# gibberish command not found on bash terminal startup

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnome-terminal, bashrc

I have run across an issue that I just cannot seem to figure out.  When I start my terminal in ubuntu (14.04) I get the message

```
sdfsdfsdi: command not found
```

As you can see it just looks like someone (maybe myself) was banging the keyboard in frustration and then accidentally wrote to some script that bash reads on initialization.  The problem is I cannot for the life of me find what script bash is reading when it encounters this gibberish.  I've looked in

```
~/.profile
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
/etc/profile
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

and none of them seem to have the gibberish phrase.  Are there other locations that bash reads from on startup that I can check?

Thanks!

Andrew

(Note this is not a critical issue, more of just a minor annoyance).

Comment: One way to figure it out would be `cd / && sudo grep -r "sdfsdfsdi"` though I won't claim it's the best way

Comment: The files you list may each source more files. You'll have to expand your search accordingly.

Comment: Also check the command which `gnome-terminal` executes to start a bash session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find which commands `bash` runs on start-up and which file those commands came from, run:

```
PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7>&2
```

The output is lengthy but the source of the gibberish will hopefully be clear.

Explanation:

- `PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> '`

  When creating an execution trace, `bash` will prepend every line with an expansion of `PS4`.  Here, we make `PS4` display the source file that is being read.
- `BASH_XTRACEFD=7`

  This sends the execution trace to `7` which is a file descriptor chosen in hopes that it is one that the `bash` start-up files will not mess with.
- `bash -xl`

  This starts bash with the options `-x`, which causes all commands to be displayed with the `PS4` prompt, and `-l` which instructs `bash` to treat this like a login shell.  If you don't get gibberish on login shells, then try it without `-l`.
- `7>&2`

  This redirects the trace output back to stderr for display on the terminal.

#### Three Refinements

Based on Geirha's comment, this version adds three improvement:

```
PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xlic ""  7>&2
```

There are three refinements here: (1) the PS4 prompt now also displays the line number as well as the file name, (2) the `-i` flag makes the shell interactive, in addition to `-l` which made it a login shell, and (3) `-c ""` causes the shell to exit after initialization is complete.

Comment: I usually recommend `PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' bash -xlic ""` for debugging the initialization files.

Comment: @geirha I like it!  I merged the improvements from your version with trace output redirection and added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, this worked out.  It turns out it was coming from the git completion script in `/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash.` Which is odd because I know that I never edited this file so it must have sneaked in there some other way.  I also really like how you explained everything John!  It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's invasive, but you can use the oldest debugging technique in the book: print stuff to mark where things are going wrong:

```
sudo tee -a /etc/profile <<<'echo /etc/profile'
sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc <<<'echo /etc/bash.bashrc'
tee -a ~/.profile <<<'echo ~/.profile'
tee -a ~/.bashrc <<<'echo ~/.bashrc'
tee -a ~/.bash_aliases <<<'echo ~/.bash_aliases'
bash -l
```

That will narrow down the region where the garbage is, and then you can focus your search.